# IPv6 default route lost after 30 minutes

Tags: networking, firewall, ipv6

I have an ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.7.3) system which loses its IPv6 default route after the first RA it received expires (30 minutes).

Here's what the routing table looked like when the system booted:

```
# ip -6 route
2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1480 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1480 pref medium
default via fe80::ce46:d6ff:feb0:f6b1 dev ens192  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1747sec mtu 1480 hoplimit 64 pref high
```

30 minutes later, I saw this:

```
# ip -6 route
2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1480 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1480 pref medium
default via fe80::ce46:d6ff:feb0:f6b1 dev ens192  proto ra  metric 1024  expires -8sec mtu 1480 hoplimit 64 pref high
```

And then, a few seconds after that, I saw this:

```
# ip -6 route
2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1480 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1480 pref medium
```

tcpdump shows the system is receiving RAs:

```
#tcpdump -vv ip6
tcpdump: listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:34:21.842483 IP6 (class 0xe0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 96) fe80::ce46:d6ff:feb0:f6b1 > ip6-allnodes: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 96
        hop limit 64, Flags [none], pref high, router lifetime 1800s, reachable time 0s, retrans time 0s
          source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): cc:46:d6:b0:f6:b1
            0x0000:  cc46 d6b0 f6b1
          advertisement interval option (7), length 8 (1):  30000ms
            0x0000:  0000 0000 7530
          mtu option (5), length 8 (1):  1480
            0x0000:  0000 0000 05c8
          rdnss option (25), length 24 (3):  lifetime 60s, addr: ordns.he.net
            0x0000:  8075 0000 003c 2001 0470 0020 0000 0000
            0x0010:  0000 0000 0002
          prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
            0x0000:  40c0 0027 8d00 0009 3a80 0000 0000 2001
            0x0010:  XXXX XXXX XXXX 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

So I assumed that, since tcpdump sees the RAs, the firewall must be dropping the RAs (I'm using UFW to manage iptables).

So I disabled ufw and waited til I saw another RA in tcpdump.
Still no default route.

What's going on?
Am I missing something simple?

Edit:

After more digging into the system...
It looks like the networking service is failing to start on boot.

```
# systemctl status networking
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-09-11 16:47:36 MST; 1min 39s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 5650 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 5599 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (cod=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5650 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 11 16:47:31 asdf systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Sep 11 16:47:33 asdf ifup[5650]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.ens192
Sep 11 16:47:35 asdf ifup[5650]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sep 11 16:47:35 asdf ifup[5650]: Failed to bring up ens192.
Sep 11 16:47:36 asdf systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 11 16:47:36 asdf systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Sep 11 16:47:36 asdf systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 11 16:47:36 asdf systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

# journalctl -xe

Sep 11 16:47:35 asdf sh[5593]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sep 11 16:47:35 asdf sh[5593]: Failed to bring up ens192.
Sep 11 16:47:35 asdf systemd[1]: ifup@ens192.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 11 16:47:35 asdf ifup[5650]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sep 11 16:47:35 asdf ifup[5650]: Failed to bring up ens192.
Sep 11 16:47:36 asdf systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 11 16:47:36 asdf systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

Now...What's interesting to me about that is if I do this:

```
# ifdown --force ens192 && ifup ens192
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
Waiting for DAD... Done
root@az-unixweb-1:~# ip -6 route
2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens192  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 pref medium
default via 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1 dev ens192  metric 1024  pref medium
```

I can also start and stop the networking service successfully after doing the ifdown --force.

As you can see, it is now taking the configuration from my /etc/network/interfaces file, which looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface ens192 inet static
        address a.b.c.d
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        gateway a.b.c.r
        dns-nameserver a.b.c.dns
iface ens192 inet6 static
        address 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::44
        netmask 64
        gateway 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1
        dns-nameserver 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::42
        dns-nameserver 2001:470:20::2
auto ens192
```

With this configuration, I expect exactly what the routing table above gives me.
This configuration has remained unchanged since I initially asked the question. If I reboot, the service fails again and it's back to using an autoconfigured address, plus my configured address, plus only using the RA-advertised route (for 30 minutes).

So... It's still broken and services that depend on the networking service to start also fail on startup.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that something else is bringing the interface up before systemd itself gets to the networking service. Research into that `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` error indicates that it's often because something tries to assign an address that is already assigned. If I change /etc/defaults/networking to have CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=no, the service starts, and my interface has the address it is supposed to AS WELL as an autoconf address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's not really the ideal solution, since I wanted a fully static configuration, but I do have a working configuration, now.

**I removed the gateway line from my `/etc/network/interfaces` file and rebooted.** That allowed the networking service to start on boot and resulted in me having a default route configured via the RA mechanism. The difference now is that the route is actually being refreshed every 30 seconds, when my router sends out an RA, whereas before, with the gateway line specified in that file, the RA route was never refreshed and eventually timed out.

Honestly this feels like a bug to me, unless I'm missing something fundamental...